# Cheerio not working as expected in a Google Cloud function

Tags: request, axios, cheerio

I have this piece of code :

```
 const response = await request.get(
    `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yURRmWtbTbo&sp=EgIQAQ%253D%253D`
  );
  const $ = cheerio.load(response, {
    decodeEntities: false
  });
  console.log(
      $(
        ".video-list-item.related-list-item.show-video-time.related-list-item-compact-video"
      ).html()
  );
```

It works great on my local machine but if I execute this code in a cloud function, it returns `null`. I checked this is the exact same code, packages also have the same version. I'm not sure what's going on here. I also tried with axios...

What's even stranger is that it works well on both machines with a different youtube ID: I_izvAbhExY

**EDIT:**

Here is a diff check of the response from my local machine (to the left) and from the cloud function machine (to the right) :

https://www.diffchecker.com/dKaN5kBx

Comment: Sometimes requesting youtube redirects to CAPTCHA. Are you sure you're getting page content correctly?

Comment: Seems like youtube detected you are not requesting from a browser. Add some browser like headers to your request, like User-Agent. Then tell me the result.

Comment: It didn't change anything. What's weird is that it works with a different youtube ID :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= I_izvAbhExY&sp=EgIQAQ%253D%253D

Comment: What type of information you are trying to get? cant you use youtube's api?

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any class with "video-list-item" in the code on the right. Maybe that's the problem?

Some parts of the webpage are missing in the source code on the right. So the selector

```
$(
    ".video-list-item.related-list-item.show-video-time.related-list-item-compact-video"
  )
```

will return `null` or `undefined`